# How to obtain weight vector for class frequencies list in imbalanced multiclassification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have four classes with a classlabel list as follows.

```
classLabelList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Each class has a specific frequency in a list given below.

```
classFrequencyList = [150751, 79995, 65858, 69102]
```

Class `0` is overly represented in the data whereas class `2` is having least representation.
Now I want to calculate a weight vector such that overly represented class has a lower weight and other minority classes has greater weight. Later I will apply this weight to my categoricalcrossentropy loss.

Is there any way I can find the weight vector given  `classFrequencyList` using `sklearn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight`, just that the `y` has to be the array of the class labels for the samples.

```
import sklearn 

class_weights = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', classLabelList, y)
```